# How much genetic divergence must there be to yield two different species?

Tags: human-genetics

I read that humans are a few percent Neanderthal. So how much difference between egg and sperm is needed for there to be no offspring. That is, for there to be two different species? Is this a measurable quantity or just a random genetic mismatch?

Comment: The 'no offspring' barrier is a bit arbitrary, I'm afraid. Consider pizzly/grolar bears, who are perfectly fertile. And yet grizzly bears and polar bears are considered two different species.

Comment: Could you please add a reference to where you read something. It helps to give a frame of reference to people trying to answer your question. An article in the Daily Herald, is different than one that you read in Popular Science is different that one you read in Nature.

Comment: Try reading this first, [Reproductive Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproductive_isolation) , and then if this still doesn't answer your question or if it raises other questions, please feel free to edit your question.

Comment: Besides "_species_" being an ill-defined term, the required genetic divergence isn't appropriately characterized by "how much" genetic change, but rather what precise genes have changed in what ways to prevent population mixing. A single gene or two might cause it, if it affects a critical function, say having to do with sperm/ovum compatibility.